# QuickLook Plugin UTI on Big Sur not working properly

Tags: xcode, macos-big-sur, quicklook, uti

I have a strange issue with a QuickLook generator I'm building for Google Drive.

The "*.gdoc" files on my computer have a UTI of be.gdoc.quicklook as shown by running `mdls -name kMDItemContentType /Volumes/GoogleDrive/My\ Drive/*.gdoc`in terminal

And my QL generator `qlmanage -m` correctly shows that `be.gdoc.quicklook -> /Users/itai/Library/QuickLook/GoogleDriveGenerator.qlgenerator`

Moreover, when I run `qlmanage -p -c "be.gdoc.quicklook" some_file.gdoc` I get the correct preview of the file contents using the generator

But when I run `qlmanage -p some_file.gdoc` my custom generator isn't invoked. Likewise, when I press spacebar in finder my custom generator is not invoked

```
$ qlmanage -p dummy.gdoc 
Testing Quick Look preview with files:
    dummy.gdoc
2021-09-03 16:06:26.637 qlmanage[74068:14229274] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x6e03, name = 'com.apple.coredrag'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.
2021-09-03 16:06:26.678 qlmanage[74068:14229274] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x854b, name = 'com.apple.tsm.portname'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.

$ qlmanage -p dummy.gdoc -c "be.gdoc.quicklook"
Testing Quick Look preview with files:
    dummy.gdoc
    - force using content type UTI: be.gdoc.quicklook
2021-09-03 16:06:33.320 qlmanage[74083:14229555] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x6703, name = 'com.apple.coredrag'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.
2021-09-03 16:06:33.356 qlmanage[74083:14229555] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x7e03, name = 'com.apple.tsm.portname'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.
```

The permission denied error is not related in my opinion because in the `-c` case everything works. Moreover, `qlmanage -p some_picture.jpeg` also shows that permission denied error, so it seems to be an error that shows up even for System plugins.

Please note that this same plugin worked just fine on Mojave. Note also that I have other custom QL plugins that seem to work just fine on their respective UTI files